# JQuery Upload File : Single file with no "alerte message : Maximum number of files exceeded"

Tags: jquery, upload

I finally use the parameter "maxfile to 1" but what once we try to upload a second file, a new line appears with the error message 'Maximum number of files exceeded'.

```
    'max_number_of_files' => 1, (file : UploadHandler.php)
```

Now, i want to hide this "event" `'max_number_of_files' => 'Maximum number of files exceeded',`. I mean, if I try to upload a new file, nothing has to appear above the first uploaded file.

Any advices ?

Regards,

Comment: Post the relevant code  as well

Comment: In fact, i would like to "block" the user as he can't even try to upload a new file. Maybe we can try a function to "replace the previous file by the new one" ? What do you think

Comment: I think the best approach would be to notify the user that there is already a file, and does he want to replace the existing one with new one. based on his response, you need to proceed with  your functionality.